# Sparse estimated data recommender system

Tags: clustering, estimation, predictive-models, recommender-system, sparse

### Premise:

For a product and a user, the system has to recommend him/her other non-users related with him/her that are most likely to be interested in that same product.

### Available data includes:

1. **Non-users:**

   - Basic demographics (*e.g.* age, gender, location, date of birth).
   - Simple relationship with other users.
2. **Users:**

   - Non-user data
   - Products the user interacted with in the past (*e.g.* datetime, level of interaction).
   - System usage data (*e.g.* time since last login, first login datetime).
3. **Product:**

   - Value.
   - Datetime when the product was made first available.

### Data properties:

- Most non-users have very few relationships with other users (not uncommon to have only 1).
- Most users have few medium interactions and even less strong interactions with products.
- Demographic information is quite similar among all users (unevenly distributed).
- Total registered interactions for some products are quite limited in number.

### Initial approach:

1. Create a matrix of product interactions and users.
2. Normalise the data.
3. Assign to each non-user the average score for each product, calculated from the scores of all users that have relationships with that non-user (using the above matrix).
4. Perform a KNN for the user and the other non-users he/she is related to. Use their "estimated" product interaction scores to obtain most similar non-users.

### Question:

What other approaches could be applied in order to reduce bias and/or increase recommendation quality?